# Entity form submission sending email

Tags: 8, entities

I'm working on entity form using the module "eform" in D8.

I would like it to send email when the user submits a form. It was done using some other modules rules and entity rules, but since "entity rules" is not released yet in D8, I couldn't find a way to send submission email.
Is there any module to make it possible or should I create a custom module to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I've asked the question multiple times. It appears that we need to wait for Rules. For the time-being, I'm using the built-in drupal contact form + contact_storage module for form. It's not the best, but it works.

Comment: The thing is I should use eForm..

Comment: Why? contact + contact_storage *is* entity forms. We (contact_storage maintainers) are very happy to receive patches to add additional features, that we eventually also want to get in core.

Answer (score 0):

I can see 2 ways to achieve it programmatically.

1. Using Hooks.
2. Using the Events system.

1) You can use "[hook_ENTITY_TYPE_insert](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_ENTITY_TYPE_insert/8.2.x)" in your module file. In this function/hook, you can trigger mail.

2) I believe using event system will be a better approach instead of using hooks. Currently, Drupal core doesn't provide any Events for entity(node) transactions like add/edit/delete. For this purpose, you can use "[Entity Events](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_events)" module. All steps are given module page. If you don't want to use the contributed module, you can create your own events to listen to entity-based transactions.